# Code to detect HTTP/2 Rapid Reset Attack vulnerability

Tags: ddos, http2

Is there code/library to detect this vulnerability? I have been searching online and do not find any

We are using Cloudflare which has [fixed the issue](https://blog.cloudflare.com/technical-breakdown-http2-rapid-reset-ddos-attack/) but government says "we may" have the vulnerability as they have detected that we are using HTTP/2

It would be great if we could provide a tool for detecting it and stating that it outputs that we are safe from the vulnerability (yeah it would be great if they provided it but sometimes one has to guard one's back)